# how to deploy springboot app in windows server 2012?

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, windows-server-2012

I'm developing a SpringBoot app and I need to deploy it on a remote server running Windows Server 2012. I tried running the app from eclipse there, and i can access locally from the server, but when I try to access from other devide using the IP of the server it has no response. Any idea about how can I deploy it? The app runs on port 8080, so the URL is locally: localhost:8080/start/
but when i access XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/access/ there is no answer

I beg you to help me, I'm desperate

Answer (score 0):

When you run your application in eclipse , the tomcat might be configured to listen to `localhost`, but still if your remote is in the same network as your local system you should be able to access the endpoints without fail.Make sure that the remote is open to the public , otherwise it won't be accessible to other devices.

If you are using spring-boot to create an executable war or jar to be deployed to a remote server for long term , you can use the **Windows service wrapper** provided by springboot itself to register your application as a service in windows.

Please read the [doc](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw) and the [sample code](https://github.com/snicoll/spring-boot-daemon) to implement it.

Answer (score -2):

You may have to enable CORS--- @CrossOrigin on top of your controller class where you have you @RestController annotation